# Error while trying to call JetAttachDatabase from ESENT.dll in Golang

Tags: go, system-calls, jet

I'm trying to play with the "ESENT.dll" library in Golang. Aim is to open an ESEDB file and read some data inside.

According to MSDN, I first have to create an ESE session then attach the ESEDB file with the following functions from the library :

> JET_ERR JET_API JetInit(
> JET_INSTANCE *pinstance);

> JET_ERR JET_API JetBeginSession(
> JET_INSTANCE    instance,
> JET_SESID       *psesid,
> const char      *szUserName,
> const char      *szPassword );

> JET_ERR JET_API JetAttachDatabase(
> JET_SESID       sesid,
> const char      *szFilename,
> JET_GRBIT       grbit );

So, that's what I tried to do :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    esentDLL = syscall.NewLazyDLL("ESENT.dll")
    instance uintptr
    sesid uintptr
)

func main() {

    esedbFilePath, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(".\\SRUDB.dat")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Done")
    }
    initEseSession()
    attachEseDB(esedbFilePath)

}

func initEseSession() {

    JetInit := esentDLL.NewProc("JetInit")
    JetBeginSession := esentDLL.NewProc("JetBeginSession")

    fmt.Print("JetInit call... ")
    rInit, _, _ := JetInit.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&instance)))

    if rInit != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Error", rInit)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Done")
    }

    fmt.Print("JetBeginSession call... ")
    rBeginSession, _, _ := JetBeginSession.Call(
        instance,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&sesid)),
        0,
        0)

    if rBeginSession != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Error", rBeginSession)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Done")
    }

}

func attachEseDB(esedbFilePath *uint16) {

    JetAttachDatabase := esentDLL.NewProc("JetAttachDatabase")

    fmt.Print("JetAttachDatabase call... ")
    rAttachDatabase, _, _ := JetAttachDatabase.Call(
        sesid,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&esedbFilePath)),
        0)

    if rAttachDatabase != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Error :", rAttachDatabase)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Done")
    }

}
```

But, after JetAttachDatabase call, I have an unspecified error.

```
JetInit call... Done
JetBeginSession call... Done
JetAttachDatabase call... Error : 4294965485
```

Could you help me please?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

I made some changes. Error code return by the ESENT.dll is a 'long' type. So I converted the uintptr returned by the function call to a 'int32' type.

Now I got the good error codes.

Plus, I discovered that absolute path for the ESEDB file always return the error "No shuch file".

This issue is solved using relative path.

But now, thats what I have :

```
Call JetCreateInstance...       Done    : Code 0 (The function succeeded)
Call JetInit...                 Done    : Code 0 (The function succeeded)
Call JetBeginSession...         Done    : Code 0 (The function succeeded)
Call JetAttachDatabase...       Error   : Code -1032 (The file cannot be accessed because the file is locked or in use)
Call JetOpenDatabase...         Error   : Code -1203 (There is no such database)
Call JetGetDatabaseInfo...      Error   : Code -1010 (There is an invalid database ID)
Call JetCloseDatabase...        Error   : Code -1010 (There is an invalid database ID)
Call JetDetachDatabase...       Error   : Code -1203 (There is no such database)
Call JetEndSession...           Done    : Code 0 (The function succeeded)
Call JetTerm...                 Done    : Code 0 (The function succeeded)
```

I made some tests with other ESEDB files (SRUDB.dat, spartan.edb, WebCacheV01.dat...) but I always got this issue.

ESEDB files were dumped from my own computer and others, after clean shutdown, so I don't understand why I have this issue...

Answer (score 1):

According to [Extensible Storage Engine Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/extensible-storage-engine-error-codes):

> A [JET_ERR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/jet-err) value of **zero** should be interpreted as success.
>
> A [JET_ERR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/jet-err) value that is **greater than zero** should be interpreted as a warning.
>
> A [JET_ERR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/jet-err) value that is **less than zero** should be interpreted as an error.

Therefore, the error code must be converted to signed integer:

```golang
fmt.Println("Error :", int32(rAttachDatabase))
```

Then we get error code `-1811`, which means `JET_errFileNotFound` (The file was not found.)

It will not be superfluous to check the return value `lastErr`:

```golang
func attachEseDB(esedbFilePath *uint16) {

    JetAttachDatabase := esentDLL.NewProc("JetAttachDatabase")

    fmt.Print("JetAttachDatabase call... ")
    rAttachDatabase, _, err := JetAttachDatabase.Call(
        sesId,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&esedbFilePath)),
        0)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s ", err)
    }

    if rAttachDatabase != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Error :", int32(rAttachDatabase))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Done")
    }

}
```

In my case, the result was:

```
JetAttachDatabase call... The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Error : -1811
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake using 'uintptr' directly. You're right!